# Integral of binomial distribution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, distributions

I did not get the expected result of $1$ when I tried to integrate the binomial distribution in different ways (v10.0):

```
Integrate[
 Binomial[n, k] p^k (1 - p)^(n - k),
 {p, 0, 1},
 Assumptions -> n >= 0 && k >= 0 && k <= n
 ]
```

expected: $1$
observed: $1/(1 + n)$

```
Assuming [
 {{n, k} \[Element] Integers, n >= 0, k >= 0 && k <= n},
 Integrate[
  Binomial[n, k] p^k (1 - p)^(n - k),
  {p, 0, 1}
  ]
 ]
```

expected: $1$
observed: $1/(1 + n)$

```
Integrate[
 p^k (1 - p)^(n - k),
 {p, 0, 1},
 Assumptions -> n >= 0 && k >= 0 && k <= n
 ]
```

expected: $\frac{1}{n \choose k} = \frac{k! (n - k)!}{n!} = \frac{\Gamma(k + 1) \Gamma(n - k + 1)}{\Gamma[n + 1]}$
observed: $\frac{\Gamma(1 + k) \Gamma(1 - k + n)}{\Gamma[2 + n]}$

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binomial distribution is a discrete one. Instead of *integrating over $p$*, one has to _sum over all $k$:

```
Sum[Binomial[n, k] p^k (1 - p)^(n - k), {k, 0, n}]
```

> 1

Comment: That was embarrassing... I confused the parameter and the variable of a  distribution. You saved me from wasting a lot of paper! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hehe. You're welcome. You may delete the question if it's too embarrassing for you. It will be closed quite likely, anyways.

Comment: Btw: Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange!